# In postgresql how to find periodic intervals

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, intervals

I am making a meeting booking application. I have a meeting table with a period
for periodic meetings.

```
create table meeting (
    id SERIAL, 
    name varchar, 
    date_start date not null, 
    period interval default '0:0:0');
```

And en event table where I will put stuff for a specific meeting. Now I want to know what meeting ther is in this month. (Or week) So I do something like

```
select name, date_start + period*6 as next_event 
from admin.routine 
where date_trunc('month', current_date) < (date_start + period*6) 
and (date_start + period*6) < date_trunc('month', current_date) + '1month';
```

But i dont want to test for every N in perod*N there is. (N = 6 here).

And how can I use next_event as alias in the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table (a subquery in from clause):

```
select name, next_event
from (
    select name, date_start + period*6 as next_event 
    from meeting
    ) sub
where date_trunc('month', current_date) < next_event
and next_event < date_trunc('month', current_date) + '1month';
```